# Detect whether IIS 6.0 metabase compatibility is installed

Tags: vb.net, iis-7, windows-7, installation

I have built a web setup project using VS 2008, wherein I need to check whether IIS 6.0 Metabase compatibility is installed. I tried it by accessing registry keys specifed in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2702215/how-do-i-check-whether-iis-6-management-compatibility-feature-has-been-installed) in custom actions. But when I run the installer, I the key comes out to be blank irrespective of whether metabase compatibility is installed.

To further check the problem, I created a Console app to access the same keys. When I run it on win7, the app fails. Then, I ran it in WinXP SP3 compatibility mode and it ran perfectly.

Can someone help with this. I am open to other bullet-proof means of detecting  whether IIS 6.0 Metabase compatibility is installed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up checking for presence of the file "%windir%\system32\inetsrv\metadata.dll".

Answer (score 0):

HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS-WebServer-Package~31bf3856ad364e35~amd64~~6.1.7600.16385\Updates

Check if IIS-IIS6ManagementCompatibility is 1. 1 means installed, 0 means not installed.

---

Other check boxes also reflect to something under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Component Based Servicing\Packages\Microsoft-Windows-IIS*

Comment: whats about HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\InetStp\Components ?