# VBS Windows 64bit/32bit registry read problem

Tags: windows, vbscript, 64-bit, 32-bit

What I am trying to achieve I feel should be fairly simple yet it is driving me totally insane.

Background:
We run a system monitoring tools across our clients which has the ability to run .vbs scripts remotely. This works very well normally.

What I am trying to achieve currently is being able to read a line from the registry on both 32bit versions of windows and 64 bit versions.

The Client side.exe which monitors the machine runs as a 32bit process on BOTH platforms (This is the trick).

I want to read a key from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\ for example. My script works perfectly fine on 32bit. example: objRegistry.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\anything")

The problem I have is when I run this same line on a 64bit folder is is automatically looking in the wow64node folder. Example: objRegistry.RegRead("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\wow64node\").

I need to have it checking in EXACTLY the same place.

The key it is reading is part of a program that runs both 32bit and 64bit versions which is why it is not installed in the wow64node folder.

At this point I am unable to run the .VBS script as a 64bit process which would solve my problem entirely as it would then not look in the wow64node folder.

If anyone has any ideas at all please let me know.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I read 64-bit Registry values from VBScript running as a an msi post-installation task?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229760/how-do-i-read-64-bit-registry-values-from-vbscript-running-as-a-an-msi-post-insta)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I read 64-bit Registry values from VBScript running as a an msi post-installation task?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229760/how-do-i-read-64-bit-registry-values-from-vbscript-running-as-a-an-msi-post-inst)

Answer (score 4):

I solved it using this piece of code.

```
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
sPath = ReadRegStr (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\ASP.NET\2.0.50727.0", "Path", 64)
WScript.Echo sPath

' Reads a REG_SZ value from the local computer's registry using WMI.
' Parameters:
'   RootKey - The registry hive (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390788(VS.85).aspx for a list of possible values).
'   Key - The key that contains the desired value.
'   Value - The value that you want to get.
'   RegType - The registry bitness: 32 or 64.
'
Function ReadRegStr (RootKey, Key, Value, RegType)
    Dim oCtx, oLocator, oReg, oInParams, oOutParams

    Set oCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
    oCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", RegType

    Set oLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set oReg = oLocator.ConnectServer("", "root\default", "", "", , , , oCtx).Get("StdRegProv")

    Set oInParams = oReg.Methods_("GetStringValue").InParameters
    oInParams.hDefKey = RootKey
    oInParams.sSubKeyName = Key
    oInParams.sValueName = Value

    Set oOutParams = oReg.ExecMethod_("GetStringValue", oInParams, , oCtx)

    ReadRegStr = oOutParams.sValue
End Function
```

Thank you Helen for your help!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `WshShell.RegRead`, use the WMI [`StdRegProv`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393664.aspx) class — it allows you to specify whether you want to read from the 32-bit or 64-bit registry. Check out this MSDN article for more info and examples:

[Requesting WMI Data on a 64-bit Platform](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa393067.aspx)

Comment: I have tried this and it doesn't want to let me run StdRegProv. strDateDefs = objRegistry.ReadRegStr (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\ESET\ESET Security\CurrentVersion\Info", "ScannerVersion", 64). The error code I am getting is "Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Object doesn't support this property or method: 'ReadRegStr'"

Comment: @Ben: `ReadRegStr` isn't a `StdRegProv` method, it's a custom function from [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1229760/how-do-i-read-64-bit-registry-values-from-vbscript-running-as-a-an-msi-post-insta/1230013#1230013) that wraps all the code needed to do the job. You should have call it like this: `strDateDefs = ReadRegStr (HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\ESET\ESET Security\CurrentVersion\Info", "ScannerVersion", 64)`.