# Find registry key using Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, registry

I want to check if a user has Microsoft SQL Native Client 2008 (sqlncli10) or Native Client 2012 (sqlncli11) installed.

```
Dim key As String
Dim myShell As Object
Set myShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")

key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion\Version"
'key = "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\CurrentVersion"

Dim strKey As String
strKey = myShell.RegReadkey(key)
```

When looking for the native client I receive the error:

> Invalid root in registry key "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion\Version"

but when trying the Windows NT version it works fine.

I replaced HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE with HKLM: but that doesn't work either.

**EDIT**

I just figured it out I think. When I checked in the registry it exists in the 64-bit section. However VBA checks in 32-bit and the root for SOFTWARE becomes Wow6432Node. So it checks in Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server and the key does not exist there. But I have found another path SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10 alternatively 11 which exist in both 32-bit and 64-bit.

Comment: This has already been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604276/check-if-registry-key-exists

Comment: Same result. I can find Windows NT but when doing exactly the same thing for SQL Native Client it can't find it.

Answer (score 1):

This code works for me:

```
Dim key As String
Dim objShell As Object

Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
key = objShell.RegRead _
    ("HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\SQLNCLI11\CurrentVersion\Version")
```

I just did this in the Excel 2010 VBA editor.

Comment: That's exaclty what my code does as well and for some reasson it says that it's an invalid root in registry key for everything but the Win NT version. Made an ugly fugly workaround to check which dll that exists in system32.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is a permission problem checking from VBA. I suppose you could check this by having Excel execute as an Admin. At least you know your code was ok! Glad you have a workaround.

Comment: I just found out I think. When I checked in the registry it exists in the 64-bit section. However VBA being legacy it is in 32-bit and the root for SOFTWARE is Wow6432Node. So it checks in Wow6432Node\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server and it does not exist there.

But I have found another path SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server Native Client 10 alternatively 11 which exist in both 32-bit and 64-bit. Thanks for the help though.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of WScript use below function. This will work for both 32 and 64 bits.

```
Function ReadRegistry(RootKey, Key As String, Value As String, Optional RegType As Integer = 32) As String


    ' Reads a REG_SZ value from the local computer's registry using WMI.
    ' Parameters:
    '   RootKey - The registry hive (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390788(VS.85).aspx for a list of possible values).
    '   Key - The key that contains the desired value.
    '   Value - The value that you want to get.
    '   RegType - The registry bitness: 32 or 64.


    Dim oCtx, oLocator, oReg, oInParams, oOutParams

    Set oCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
    oCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", RegType

    Set oLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator")
    Set oReg = oLocator.ConnectServer("", "root\default", "", "", , , , oCtx).Get("StdRegProv")

    Set oInParams = oReg.Methods_("GetStringValue").InParameters
    oInParams.hDefKey = RootKey
    oInParams.sSubKeyName = Key
    oInParams.sValueName = Value

    Set oOutParams = oReg.ExecMethod_("GetStringValue", oInParams, , oCtx)

    ReadRegistry = oOutParams.sValue
End Function

Sub test()
  Const HKEY_CURRENT_USER = &H80000001
  MsgBox ReadRegistry(HKEY_CURRENT_USER, "Software\Microsoft\Office\15.0\Outlook\Security", "OutlookSecureTempFolder")
End Sub
```

Comment: Santosh -- you helped me immensely with some JSON issues last year (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51802512/why-cant-i-assign-to-a-variable-a-json-value-that-i-can-see-in-debug-mode).  I have a related issue I'd like to run by you to see if there's any use trying to pursue it any further.  Can I contact you directly or do I have to start a thread?