# Why can't I assign to a variable a JSON value that I can see in Debug mode?

Tags: json, ms-access

I’ve run into an issue retrieving values from a non-itemized JSON object.  I thought it was simple do so … Just reference the object with the field you want (e.g. JSON(“title”).  But I cannot retrieve a value even though it IS there.

This code demonstrates what I’m talking about.  (Be sure to put a breakpoint on the “next” line, or it will run for a while.)  The strID and strTitle values are not assigned and do not print out.  But if you go to the immediate window and type

? JSON2("ID") 
? JOON2(“title”)

You get the values.  What am I doing wrong?  Why can’t I get these values into variables?

```
Sub testMovie2()

Dim Url As String, data As String, data2 As String
Dim xml As Object, JSON As Object, JSON2 As Object, colObj As Object, colobj2 As Object, item, item2
Dim strID As String, strTitle As String

Url = "https://www.tiff.net/data/films-events-2018.json"
data = getHTTP(Url)
Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(data)
Set colObj = JSON("items")
For Each item In colObj
    Url = "https://www.tiff.net/data/films/" & item("id") & ".JSON"
    data2 = getHTTP(Url)
    Set JSON2 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(data2)
    strID = JSON2("ID")
    Debug.Print strID
    strTitle = JSON2("Title")
    Debug.Print strTitle
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `getHTTP()` ? Could it be not finished yet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JSON2` is a dictonary object and to retrieve element from dictonary use below

**with key**

`JSON2.item("id")` 
`JSON2.item("title")`

OR

**with index**

`JSON2.Items()(4)`
`JSON2.Items()(5)`

---

By default dictionary objects are case sensitive

So `JSON2("ID")` not equals to `JSON2("id")`

To make it case insensitive use:

`JSON2.CompareMode = vbTextCompare`

---

**Code:**

```
Sub testMovie2()

    Dim url As String, data As String, data2 As String
    Dim xml As Object, JSON As Object, JSON2 As Object, colObj As Object, colobj2 As Object, item, item2
    Dim strID As String, strTitle As String

    url = "https://www.tiff.net/data/films-events-2018.json"
    data = getHTTP(url)
    Set JSON = JsonConverter.ParseJson(data)
    Set colObj = JSON("items")
    For Each item In colObj
        url = "https://www.tiff.net/data/films/" & item("id") & ".JSON"
        data2 = getHTTP(url)

        Set JSON2 = JsonConverter.ParseJson(data2)
        strID = JSON2.item("id")
        Debug.Print strID

        strTitle = JSON2.item("title")
        Debug.Print strTitle

    Next
End Sub
Function getHTTP(url) As String

    Dim data As String
    Dim xml As Object

    Set xml = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    With xml
        .Open "GET", url, False
        .setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "text/json"
        .send
        data = .responseText
    End With

    getHTTP = data

End Function
```

---

[image]

Comment: He comes through again!  I think there's been more useful information about using JSON in VBA in these three threads than there is in the rest of cyberspace.  I can't believe how rapidly I'm now acquiring the data I want.  One minor thing -- that JSON2.CompareMode = vbTextCompare statement doesn't seem to work.

Comment: You also obviated my next question with that "text/json" parameter.  I couldn't recognize the format of foreign characters in text fields of the final results, but there had to be a way that they were coming out properly on the website.  I would have spent a considerable amount of time just detailing the problem and what I had tried.  Double thanks!