# VBA to check version of software installed HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE

Tags: vba, registry, autodesk-navisworks

I'm trying to check to see which version of Navisworks installed on a users machine. I have used the example from this thread and modified [Find registry key using Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35936735/find-registry-key-using-excel-vba)

```
Function ReadRegistry(RootKey, Key As String, Value As String, Optional RegType As Integer = 32) As String

Dim oCtx, oLocator, oReg, oInParams, oOutParams

Set oCtx = CreateObject("WbemScripting.SWbemNamedValueSet")
oCtx.Add "__ProviderArchitecture", RegType

Set oLocator = CreateObject("Wbemscripting.SWbemLocator")
Set oReg = oLocator.ConnectServer("", "root\default", "", "", , , , oCtx).Get("StdRegProv")

Set oInParams = oReg.Methods_("GetStringValue").InParameters
oInParams.hDefKey = RootKey
oInParams.sSubKeyName = Key
oInParams.sValueName = Value

Set oOutParams = oReg.ExecMethod_("GetStringValue", oInParams, , oCtx)

ReadRegistry = oOutParams.sValue
```

End Function

```
Sub NavisworksVersion()
Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002
MsgBox ReadRegistry(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "Software\Autodesk\Navisworks API Runtime\18\Navisworks Manage", "Path")
```

End Sub

The code runs upto the ReadRegistry in the Function where is throws an error Invalid use of a Null

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Use the VBA debugger to step into the function to see where it throws the error.

Comment: I needed to set RegType to 64, not 32 and this works. Though how do I do this to check with version is installed on a users machine.Taken from the navisworks documentation. There are several ways to identify where Navisworks is installed but the recommended method is in fact a 2 step process. Firstly the registry key 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Autodesk\Navisworks API Runtime' contains sub keys for each installation of a Navisworks Product, vertical or OEM installed on the system. In each of these keys there is a string value called 'Path' which identifies the install location for the product