# vba RegRead returning different key string than is in the registry

Tags: vba, registry, ms-access-2016

If I run the below code I get a different registry string then when I open RegEdit and view the key directly. I an running the code using MSACCESS 2016 starting it, and also RegEdit, in Admin mode. Is there some kind a cache storing the value.

When I look at the value using RegEdit I get:
"|FromSrtCut|||FALSE|0000000|**CFI**|Check-4-It.accde||C:\Prog...."

When I use the code below, I get :
"|FromSrtCut|||FALSE|0000000|**CFI_INV**|Check-4-It.accde||C:\Prog...."

```
enter code here

Dim WshShell, bKey
Dim strKeyPath As String

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Corporate Data Design\Check-4-It"
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Lg_strTemp = WshShell.RegRead("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\" & strKeyPath & "\LiveUpdate")
Debug.Print Lg_strTemp
```

Comment: In addition, I did a search of CFI_INV in the registry and it couldn't find it.

Comment: Tried any different methods of reading the registry to see how they compare?  Eg: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9604276/check-if-registry-key-exists-using-vbscript

Comment: @Tim Well, using the other method in the link you sent, did return the value "CFI" from the registry, but when I run my original method, it still gives me "CFI_INV". So, I decided to delete all the registry keys I could fine that contained the string I am using. When I run the method you suggested, it returned a blank as expected. But, when I run mine, I still get data. It's almost like my method is looking at a different registry file. Is that possible?

Comment: Not an area I really know anything about - I wouldn't have thought so, but your results definitely point in that direction...

Comment: ? It might be related to 32/64 bit differences in the registry ?  If you're running a 32bit process on a 64bit client it seems registry calls to HKCU\SOFTWARE\XXX may be redirected to HKCU\SOFTWARE\Wow6432Node\XXX   See if that might explain what you're seeing.

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that as well. I made sure there was nothing in the wow6432Node as well. Very strange. Only happening on one PC so far. I've tested in on 4 others. Weird.